# Laravel not redirects page after sending mail

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-mail

I am sending a mail and after mail is send I want to redirect user to a specific url

```php
$mail = Mail::send('test.mail', ['a' => 'a'], function (Message $message) {
            $message->to(['hod@vu.edu.pk', 'student@vu.edu.pk',]);

            $message->from('stms@vu.edu.pk');
            $message->subject('Test Mail');
        });

//        dd($mail);
        return response()->redirectToRoute('allocate_supervisor')
            ->with('message', 'Supervisor Assigned and sent to HoD for approval.');
```

I have tried to return redirect()->route(), url(), and redirect('allocate_supervisor') but each time same issue.

dd($mail); works fine and shows output but on redirect it shows blank page.

Also request status code is 200.

Also tried

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

before return still no output

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: I believe it's `return redirect()->to('allocate_supervisor')->with(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to generate a RedirectResponse instance. The simplest method is to use the global redirect helper:

```
return redirect('/allocate_supervisor');
```

make sure 'allocate_supervisor' route must be present in your web.php file.

if you have named routes, you may use route() method.

```
return redirect()->route('/allocate_supervisor');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling storePhase function from store function and returning response from storePhase function which was being overridden in store function and I was receiving blank page...

I moved this response code to store function and it worked fine.